# Android action overflow drawn on top of ActionBar

Tags: java, android

In order to have the ActionBar in my application, my main activity extends from android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity. This is how it looks:

[image]

However, when I click in the overflow action button, the options show up over the ActionBar:

[image]

I wanted to show the overflow menu under the ActionBar, as it is supposed to. How can I solve this?

I'm running Android 4.4 (KITKAT). If you need any more details, just ask. Thanks.

Here is the code of my main activity:

```
public class SendMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_send_message);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_action_bar_icon);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.activitySendMessage, new SendMessageFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_send_message, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.actionSettings) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.actionShowHistory) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SentMessagesHistoryActivity.class));
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: Actually this is the way it works with the new appcompat-v21.

Comment: So this is the new default way to show the action overflow menu? I liked the old way better...

Comment: @JoãoLourenço if you are extending the mainactivity to actionbaractivity you have to use the lollipop api

Comment: @Naruto I edited the question so you could see my code.